# Grammar: sentence structure with possessive

Tags: sentence-construction, possessives

The boy has three coats. His coats are in the closet.

According to the above sentences, is this sentence grammatically correct?

**The three boy's coats are in the closet.**

I know it is wrong, but I do not know why.

Comment: It feels better to write "The three coats of the boy are in the closet." There is no ambiguity whether it is about three boys, or just one.

Comment: Your sentence would be grammatically correct if the "boy's" were used to indicate what kind of coats they are.  For instance, a store could have four boy's coats and three girl's coats on a rack.  But that's because it's not used as a possessive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three is an adjective of quantity that describes the word "coats" not the boy, therefore; it should read: the boy's three coats are in the closet.The example you've provided is grammatically correct but it means that there are three coats that are the size and style of a boy are in the closet, which is not what you're trying to say.

Comment: Alternatively: **The boy's three coats are in the closet**.

Comment: @RonaldSole -  that is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: was i wrong?  @MichaelHarvey

Comment: You can say 'the three boy's coats'; you seem to suggest that it is wrong, when it is not.

Comment: "Three boy's coats" would generally be coats in sizes meant to fit boys, i.e. coats made for boys to wear.

Comment: They are coats made for boys to wear; the statement is a true one.